# Form Processing Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a very simple form.I want to insert the form data in mysql database.using ajax.

I need to pick data from form and send them as xml to the server.

the form is  as :

```
              <form>
                     Name:<input type="text" id=name/>
                     Contact<input type="text" id=contact/>
              </form>
```

And i am picking the data from my form using js as :

```
              function GetData(form)
                     {
                             var name=document.getelementbyid('name');
                             vat contact=document.getelementbyid('contact');
                     }

               function Ajax
                        {
                            " Here i want to send the form datas as an xml to the server"
                        }
```

Can any one help me how to do this .And also how to receive the the request from server as xml and insert to database.

Just give me the proper way.Not Query string or json or jquery.I want to use xml using ajax

Thanks,

Comment: Use jQuery with ajax it is much simpler

Comment: no Jquery...i want to do it by js and ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function GetData(form)
{
var name=document.getelementbyid('name');
var contact=document.getelementbyid('contact');
Ajax(name,contact);
                     }


function Ajax(name,contact)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var response=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
//var datas='?name='+name+'&contact='+contact;
var xmlval='<name>'+name+'</name><contact>'+contact+'</contact>';
 var datas='?xmlvalue='+xmlval;
xmlhttp.open("GET",'phpfile.php'+datas,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Important question: Why do you need XML to submit?

Also, to use XML, look up SimpleXML, and to save to database, there are a lot tutorials.

**Update:** if you meant the response as XML? That's just like the same as in JS. And to use it in JS, look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dom.asp). However, in that case, uncomment the commented line and comment the next 2.

Comment: how can i pick the xml from the target page?